# Change value of mutable string

Tags: objective-c

How to change value of mutable string ? Here is what I do

```
NSString *str = @"This is string";

NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str];

str = @"New string" -> wrong incompatible pointer types assigning to NSMutableString from NSString
```

Comment: how can u declare two variables with same name in consecutive lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to use `NSMutableString` if you want to change parts of the string in place (append, insert etc.), often for performance reasons.

If you want to assign new values to the string variable, you're fine with a good old `NSString` as your last line simple assigns a complete new string object to `str`:

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setString` to replace the whole string:

```
NSString *str = @"This is string";
NSMutableString *mutableStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str];
...
[mutableStr setString:@"a different non mutable string"];
```

As indicated in another answer, a non-mutable `NSString` may be enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should initialize a `NSMutableString`:

```
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
```

You could use any other way specified in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The way you are doing it, you are not creating any instance of the `NSMutableString` class. Then, if you want to add some string to it:

```
[string appendString:@"content"];
```

Comment: According to docs, `NSMutableString` has many other initializers too.